# What's the equivalent of the "cls" command from Windows/DOS?

Tags: command-line

I used to use cmd back in windows, and the command line I used a lot, was `cls`. It's kind of like the `clear` command used in Linux, but it cleans the screen permanently.

If you use the `clear` command, it just scroll down, so that you don't see the command you where working on.

I like both a lot, but my question is, how do i get a `cls` like command, that clears the screen, and can't browse up, to see the command you where working on?

Comment: Just open new tab and close current tab :D

Comment: by the way pressing ctrl+l is much fastern than typing clear and hitting enter

Comment: It's bad habit. Try to dislearn it. You only need it rarely for some kind of ascii art, but deleting old information shouldn't be done routinely. [Read The art of unix programming](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/) for further information.

Comment: @userunknown Old information is deleted all the time. When you close a terminal window or log off a session in SSH or a virtual console. When an update replaces one version of installed software with another. When you run `apt-get --purge ...`. When cookies/cache are cleared in a browser. To think clearing a terminal--[a fundamental function of Unix-style terminals which works exactly the same way as in Windows but without the special command](http://askubuntu.com/a/239821/22949)--is somehow inconsistent with good principles for operating *nix systems, seems like a failure of the imagination.

Comment: @userunknown for me, the common use case is that i run a command that prints out a lot of information. then i want to run it again (maybe with a different param or whatever). when it's done, i want to scroll back up to where it started. without clearing the buffer, it can be hard to spot where the most recent command finished. before i bothered to google it (and found this answer), my workaround was to hold enter key for a few seconds to fill the console with a bunch of blank space

Comment: @Kip: You might be interested in learning about diff and graphical enhancements. Start your command with paramlist 1 and guide it into file1 (CMD p1a p1b p1c > CMD-1.log 2>&1), then with paramlist 2 and guide it to a second file file2 (CMD p2a p2b p2c > CMD-2.log 2>&1), then do a `diff CMD-[12].log` or with very convenient highlightening - needs installation - `tkdiff CMD-[12].log`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `reset`. This resets the whole terminal, so that may be a bit overkill though.

**Note on Konsole:**
[@Mechanical snail](https://askubuntu.com/users/64389/mechanical-snail) noticed "in Konsole 4.8.5, the old text is still there if you scroll up".
[@gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk) explained that it is "a feature. There's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for Konsole (reset and clear scrollback)."

Comment: Why is it overkill?

Comment: @zpletan Because it does a lot more than just clearing the scrollback buffer. Basically initializes the terminal as it was just opened.

Comment: OK. I often thought that `reset` was kind of a melodramatic name for Linux's `cls`, but it makes sense now. In any case, it sounds like unless you do weird stuff with terminal customization, all it *basically* does is clear the screen/buffer/whatever, yes?

Comment: @zpletan I could just quote the manual, but to put it another way: there are situations when the terminal screen gets garbled and a simple clear would not do, but resetting it back to the default settings (and clearing the buffer along the way) will result again in a usable terminal. The first few paragraphs of `man reset` page describe the additional procedure.

Comment: This doesn't work in Konsole. It just scrolls down.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail What do you exactly mean by "It just scrolls down"? It does not scroll in any way in Konsole here on my system. It completely resets the current terminal window instead and a new cursor blinks at the top of it.

Comment: @gertvdijk: When I try it in Konsole 4.8.5, the old text is still there if you scroll up.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Ah that. Well, that's more of a feature. There's Ctrl+Shift+X for Konsole (reset *and* clear scrollback).

Answer (score 19):

Add this line to `~/.bashrc` (i.e., the file called `.bashrc`, located in your home folder -- you can see it in Nautilus by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

```
alias cls='printf "\033c"'
```

Now the `cls` command will clear the screen like in Windows. It will put you back to the top of a Terminal window, with no text shown above it. (It will not delete the shell's command history.)

This works because:

- `.bashrc` runs every time a `bash` shell starts up.
- The `alias` command defines the `cls` command to run the command quoted on the right-hand side.
- `printf` command writes characters to the terminal. It accepts escape codes. The octal `033` is the character used to signal the beginning of a terminal *control code*. The *control code* `c` tells the terminal to clear itself.
- So, with this modification to `.bashrc`. running `cls` sends the necessary data to the terminal to tell it to clear itself.

Comment: A [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367075/1062019) on SO.

Comment: Note that `\033c`, or the hex variant `\x1Bc`, (ESC c) may be very terminal type specific. `printf $(tput clear)` may be a lot more portable (depends on terminfo, `man 5 terminfo`, `man terminfo`).

Answer (score 6):

In your current terminal window, just type the following:

```
printf "\033c"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is to avoid only casual rediscovery of command history, `reset` may be a viable choice.

However, bear in mind that by default, the shell logs your command history to a file as well - this is also eminently discoverable. If you want to prevent other persons from browsing your command history, you should also clean that out.

`history -c` # clear your history

Answer (score 0):

`cls` works by clearing the buffer, which is fixed 25 or 50 lines in case of DOS and Windows, respectively. You can achieve something like this by writing so many lines in the buffer that it overflows (2000 is a typical value), but then `reset` is also a viable option as @lgarzo said.