# using system("clear"); command to clean the screen yet last line printed. using GNU gcc compiler please help

Tags: gcc, programming, c

I am using 'system("clear");' command to clean the output screen yet the last line printed is displayed.I am using Geany text editor using GNU gcc compiler.Please help and tell me  clear the whole screen.

I am a college student and doing coding for the first time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There was a discussion on terminal clear commands recently: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118523/whats-the-equivalent-of-the-cls-command-from-windows-dos. Try e.g. the `printf "\033c"` command.

Comment: Note that `\033c` and `\x1Bc` (ESC c) may be terminal specific. `system("tput clear")` may be a lot more portable. See `man 5 terminfo` for more, see also `man terminfo` for avoiding the overhead of system().

Answer (score 0):

`system("clear")` fails. Try using `printf("\033c")`. This works in `geany`.